# Incluir argumentos query en la paginación de Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy desarrollando mi primer proyecto con Django y tengo un problema con la paginación. Tengo un formulario con varios campos para filtrar búsquedas y cuando realizo la búsqueda funciona perfectemente pero cuando le doy a página siguiente ya no me incluye la búsqueda.

Por ejemplo:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/buscar/?parque=ejemplo&fallo=&intervencion=&fecha_inicial=2015-12-01&fecha_final=2016-01-31
```

La pagina 2 seria:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/buscar/?pagina=2=parque=ejemplo&fallo=&intervencion=&fecha_inicial=2015-12-01&fecha_final=2016-01-31
```

Pero se queda asi:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/buscar/?pagina2
```

Ya no me incluye la búsqueda. Le he dado mil vueltas al tema y no lo consigo.

Esta es la vista:

```
@login_required
def buscar(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not request.GET.get('fecha_inicial', '') or not request.GET.get('fecha_final', ''):
            errors.append('por favor introduce fecha inicio y fecha fin ambas son requeridas.')
        else:
            parque = request.GET.get('parque', '')
            tipo = request.GET.get('tipo', '')
            maquina = request.GET.get('maquina', '')
            fallo = request.GET.get('fallo', '')
            intervencion = request.GET.get('intervencion', '')
            fecha_inicial = request.GET.get('fecha_inicial', '')
            fecha_final = request.GET.get('fecha_final', '')
            q1 = incidencias.objects.filter(Parque__icontains=parque)
            q2 = q1.filter(Tipo__icontains=tipo)
            q3 = q2.filter(Maquina__icontains=maquina)
            q4 = q3.filter(Fallo__icontains=fallo)
            q5 = q4.filter(Intervencion__icontains=intervencion)
            q = q5.filter(Fecha__range=(fecha_inicial, fecha_final))
            queryset_list = q
            paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5)

            page = request.GET.get('pagina')
            try:
                queryset = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:

                queryset = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:

                queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            context = {
                "objetc_list": queryset,
                "parte": "Lista",
            }
            return render(request, 'partes.html', context)
        return render(request, 'formulario.html',
        {'errors': errors})
```

El template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}


    {% if objetc_list %}
    <p>Partes encontrados: {{ objetc_list|length }} parte{{ objetc_list|pluralize }}.</p>
        <table class="responsive-table striped sombra">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parque</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>Maquina</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Fallo</th>
                    <th>Intervencion</th>
                    <th>OT</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 {% for obj in objetc_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ obj.Parque|capfirst }}</td>
                    <td>{{ obj.Tipo|capfirst }}</td>
                    <td>{{ obj.Maquina|capfirst }}</td>
                    <td>{{ obj.Fecha|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ obj.Fallo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ obj.Intervencion }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'miapp.views.detalleParte' pk=obj.pk %}">{{ obj.OT }}</a></td>
                </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>


  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if objetc_list.has_previous %}
    <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
    {% endif %}

        <span class="current">Pagina {{ objetc_list.number }} de {{ objetc_list.paginator.num_pages }}</span>

    {% if objetc_list.has_next %}
    <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>


{% else %}
    <p class="text-center"><strong> No hay partes para su busqueda. </strong></p>
{% endif %}



{% endblock content %}
```

El modelo:

```
class incidencias(models.Model): 

       Parque = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=LISTA_PARQUES, default='ejemplo')
       Tipo = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TIPO_INTERVENCION)
       Maquina = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=LISTA_MAQUINAS)
       Fecha = models.DateField()
       Fallo = models.CharField(max_length=3)
       Sintoma = models.TextField(blank=True)
       Intervencion = models.TextField()
       Observaciones = models.TextField(blank=True)
       Tec1 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LISTA_TECNICOS)
       Tec2 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LISTA_TECNICOS)
       Tec3 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LISTA_TECNICOS, blank=True)
       Tec4 = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LISTA_TECNICOS, blank=True)
       OT = models.CharField(max_length=15)

       class Meta:
          verbose_name = 'incidencia'
          order_with_respect_to = 'Maquina'



       def __unicode__(self):
          return '%s - %s - %s - %s' % (self.Tipo, self.Maquina, self.Fallo, self.OT)

    class incidenciasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ('Tipo', 'Maquina', 'Fallo', 'Fecha', 'OT')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías pasar manualmente los parámetros de la URL a tu template obviando el parámetro `pagina` (como lo propuesto en este [Snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1592/)), en tu caso sería algo asi:

```
@login_required
def buscar(request):
    ...
    parametros = request.GET.copy() # Es una copia del GET
    if parametros.has_key('pagina'):
        del parametros['pagina']
    ...
    context['parametros'] = parametros
    ...
```

Y en tu template:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    {% if objetc_list.has_previous %}
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.previous_page_number }}&{{parametros.urlencode}}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
    {% endif %}

        <span class="current">Pagina {{ objetc_list.number }} de {{ objetc_list.paginator.num_pages }}</span>

    {% if objetc_list.has_next %}
    <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.next_page_number }}&{{parametros.urlencode}}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

En el template, estoy haciendo uso de la función [QueryDict.urlencode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode) del `GET` para pasar sus parámetros al formato aceptado por la URL:

```
>>> request.GET
<QueryDict: {'a': ['1'], 'c': ['3'], 'b': ['2']}>
>>> request.GET.urlencode()
'a=1&c=3&b=2'
```

Esto finalemente te ayuda a conseguir lo que quieres:

```
?pagina=10&a=1&c=3&b=2
```

---

Otra opción que a mi me funciona muy bien es usar [`django-datatables-view`](https://bitbucket.org/pigletto/django-datatables-view) para manejar el procesamiento en el lado del servidor usando [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/), te olvidas de estar lidiando con la paginación, la búsqueda y el ordenamiento por columnas. Puedes lograr algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! la verdad es que el tema de la paginacion es un tanto desesperante. No conocia DataTables, en mi aplicacion muestro practicamente todo en tablas me será de gran utilidad.

Comment: @Eibi76 de nada! No olvides marcar la respuesta que consideras es la correcta para que tu pregunta no quede en el aire

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo [`django-haystack`](http://haystacksearch.org/) para tus búsquedas, es un pontente paquete que soporta diferentes servicios de búsqueda ya que cuenta con sus respectivos backends.

Te facilitará la vida.

A simple vista parece que el formulario donde quiera que haces la búsqueda no agrega el valor 2 a tu query página, sino que pone página 2 y ya, no agrega la query completa.

Realmente te recomiendo usar ese paquete, te evitas hacer esas peticiones manualmente y te puedes concentrar en pulir una Vista Basada en Clases con una buena plantilla.

Siento no ser de más utilidad, pero espero que te sirva mi recomendación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me he descargado haystack, me parece una opcion muy interesante. Probaré a implementarlo.

Comment: No olvides tu voto :D

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la ayuda del comentario de Cesar Bustíos he podido dar una solución rápida y simple al engorroso tema de la paginación, sobre todo si eres novel con Python y Django como es mi caso.

La vista:

```
def buscar(request):
errors = []
if request.method == 'GET':
    if not request.GET.get('fecha_inicial', '') or not request.GET.get('fecha_final', ''):
        errors.append('Por favor introduce fecha inicio y fecha fin ambas son requeridas.')
    else:
        parque = request.GET.get('parque', '')
        tipo = request.GET.get('tipo', '')
        maquina = request.GET.get('maquina', '')
        fallo = request.GET.get('fallo', '')
        intervencion = request.GET.get('intervencion', '')
        fecha_inicial = request.GET.get('fecha_inicial', '')
        fecha_final = request.GET.get('fecha_final', '')
        q1 = incidencias.objects.filter(Parque__icontains=parque)
        q2 = q1.filter(Tipo__icontains=tipo)
        q3 = q2.filter(Maquina__icontains=maquina)
        q4 = q3.filter(Fallo__icontains=fallo)
        q5 = q4.filter(Intervencion__icontains=intervencion)
        queryset_list = q5.filter(Fecha__range=(fecha_inicial, fecha_final))

        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 4)

        parametros = request.GET.copy() 
        if parametros.has_key('pagina'):
            del parametros['pagina']

        page = request.GET.get('pagina')
        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:

            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:

            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {
            "objetc_list": queryset,
            "parametros": parametros,
        }
        return render(request, 'partes.html', context)
    return render(request, 'formulario.html',
    {'errors': errors})
```

Y la paginacion del template:

```
<ul class="pagination">
{% if objetc_list.has_previous %}
<li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.previous_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
{% endif %}

    <span class="current">Pagina {{ objetc_list.number }} de {{ objetc_list.paginator.num_pages }}</span>

{% if objetc_list.has_next %}
<li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.next_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Felicidades! Que bueno que te haya funcionado

Comment: Está excelente, pero quería saber si es posible hacerlo sin necesidad de volver a cargar todos los datos nuevamente, es decir teniendo a la mano la consulta ya hecha, en mi caso los datos a consultar son muy grandes.

Answer (score 0):

porque no dejas que django lo haga todo, podrias intentar lo siguiente para realizar la paginacion, es mucho mas rapido debido a que no cargas todo al inicio de la peticion, sino que automaticamente te envia los datos que necesitas, intenta esto:

**view.py**

```
def paginar(request):
    p=Producto.objects.all()
    paginator=Paginator(p,12)
    try:
        pagina=int(request.GET.get("page","1"))
    except ValueError:
        pagina=1
    try:
        p=paginator.page(pagina)
    except(InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        p=paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return p
```

Finalmente cuando envies los datos haslo usando lo siguiente:

```
def pagina_index(request):
   return render_to_response("mihtml.html", {"items":paginar(request)})
```